# AudioCache Error - Soundpool suddenly unable to load sample from URL on Android

Tags: android, audio, sampling, soundpool

My `SoundPool` is in a `Service` and I use it to cache sounds from different urls, and play them later. The **app was working fine**, without any error, but **today it crashed**.

The **source code is the same**, nothing changed. I tried to reinstall the app, restart the device, nothing worked... After 30 minutes of trying to do something, the app started to work again on tablet, but not on my phone.

This is the code for loading the sounds:

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(14, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,100);
soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
soundPoolMap.put(key, soundPool.load(task[2], 1));
```

A `soundID` is returned by the `load()` method and it is not `0`, but **after that** *(? why after ?)*, I get the following error message:

```
11-26 15:28:09.743: E/GenericSource(187): Failed to create http source!
11-26 15:28:09.743: E/AudioCache(187): Error 1, -2147483648 occurred
11-26 15:28:09.743: D/NuPlayerDriver(187): reset(0xb8334b60)
11-26 15:28:09.744: D/NuPlayerDriver(187): notifyResetComplete(0xb8334b60)
11-26 15:06:54.597: E/SoundPool(3914): Unable to load sample: http://myurl/bet.mp3
```

The URL is fine, i tested it in a browser.

What could cause this strange bahavior?

Comment: A bad wifi or internet connection?

Comment: I don't think so, the devices are connected to the same network (on  one of them, it is working, but not on the other) and last week was everything fine on the same network. But i will test it!

Comment: Nope, it is bad on 3G network, too...